# How to visualize timeseries model prediction in Grafana

Tags: time-series, grafana, influxdb, forecasting, mlmodel

I created my own timeseries model and I exported it.

By now I'm visualizing real data in a local Grafana dashboard (I'm not using Grafana Cloud), using Influxdb as data source.

How can I visualize also my model predictions in the same dashboard? Should I predict it before and save somewhere or can I directly use the model in Grafana?

Comment: I don't understand this question. You have two time-series that you want to visualize on the same panel? Then you can simply use two queries for that. Or do you have something more complex in mind?

Comment: @markalex I have one time-series and I'm visualizing that correctly to Grafana. Now I created a forecasting model with python and I exported it. Now I want the model to predict future using data that I'm now visualizing in Grafana.